# Set not persisting in OneToMany relationship

Tags: spring-boot, rest, one-to-many

I'm trying to add a Set of classes to a single class (which *seems* to work) but when I then grab the entry, the set is empty.

What am I doing wrong?

`StartDatabase.java`
 `- InitAssetDatabase method`

```
              Set<Contact> previousContacts = new HashSet<>();
                previousContacts.add(contactRepository.findById(1));
                previousContacts.add(contactRepository.findById(2));

                LOG.info("Preloading " + repository.save(
                        new Asset(
                                "LT1001",
                                "DELL",
                                "INSPIRON 15",
                                "DI152G55BL25",
                                Asset.AssetType.LAPTOP,
                                Asset.AssetLocation.STOCK,
                                Asset.AssetCondition.NEW,
                                Date.valueOf(LocalDate.of(2022, 3, 11)),
                                Date.valueOf(LocalDate.of(2022, 3, 11)),
                                contactRepository.findById(2),
                                previousContacts,
                                null,
                                null,
                                null,
                                null
                        )));
```

`Asset.java`

```
    ...
    @OneToMany
    @JoinColumn(name = "previous_contact_id")
    private Set<Contact> previousUsers;
    ...
```

The output I finally get is:

```
[
    {
        "assetId": 1,
        "assetTag": "LT1001",
        "manufacturer": "DELL",
        "model": "INSPIRON 15",
        "identificationNumber": "DI152G55BL25",
        "type": "LAPTOP",
        "location": "STOCK",
        "condition": "NEW",
        "dateAcquired": "2022-03-11",
        "dateBuilt": "2022-03-11",
        "currentUser": {
            "contactId": 2,
            "firstName": "IT",
            "lastName": "Department",
            "currentAssets": []
        },
        "previousUsers": [],
        "dateRetired": null,
        "retiredReason": null,
        "dateDisposed": null,
        "disposedReason": null
    }
]
```

As you can see I've also tried to do this on `currentAssets` but to no effect either.

I'm using Spring boot with Rest and H2 database.

Answer (score 0):

You have forgotten to provide the `cascade` on your `@OneToMany` annotation in `Asset.java`. Cascading children is not enabled by default. For quick testing, I suggest you use `cascade = CascadeType.ALL`, i.e. `@OneToMany(cascade = CascadeType.ALL)`.

But there are further issues with your code, which I can't explain properly to you, since you only provided one side of the mapping relationship (`OneToMany`). The `ManyToOne` relationship is missing from your post.

Basically you have to map both sides of the relationship.

In `Asset.java`:

```java
    @OneToMany(cascade = CascadeType.ALL, mappedBy = "asset")
    private Set<Contact> previousUsers;
```

In `Contact.java`:

```java
    @ManyToOne
    @JoinColumn(name = "contact_id")
    private Asset asset;
```

Please consider the examples:

- My answer on a very similar question here: [How to update nested list of objects in Spring Boot?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71452246/how-to-update-nested-list-of-objects-in-spring-boot/71455475#71455475)
- [Tutorial by Baeldung](https://www.baeldung.com/hibernate-one-to-many)
- [Tutorial by VM](https://vladmihalcea.com/the-best-way-to-map-a-onetomany-association-with-jpa-and-hibernate/)
- [Beginner's guide to cascade](https://vladmihalcea.com/a-beginners-guide-to-jpa-and-hibernate-cascade-types/)

Comment: Unfortunately that didn't work. My log is stating that previousUsers is null even after adding ```CascadeType.ALL```

Comment: I expanded upon my answer and included some references, perhaps this will be more helpful.