# How to update nested list of objects in Spring Boot?

Tags: java, spring-boot, hibernate, spring-mvc, jpa

I want to update all nested entities and delete old ones.

Main entity:

```
public class Project {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    private Long projectId;

    private String name;

    private String createdDateTime;

    @OneToOne(cascade = CascadeType.ALL)
    @JoinColumn(name = "geo_json_id")
    private GeoJson geoJson;
}
```

Child entity:

```
public class GeoJson {
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    private long geoJsonId;
    private String type;

    @OneToMany(cascade = CascadeType.ALL)
    @ToString.Exclude
    private List<Feature> features = new ArrayList<Feature>();

    public GeoJson() {
    }
}
```

Feature entity:

```
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    private long fId;
    private String type;
    @OneToOne(cascade = CascadeType.ALL)
    private Properties properties;
    @OneToOne(cascade = CascadeType.ALL)
    private Geometry geometry;
}
```

I tried Patch Mapping:

```
  @PatchMapping("/projects/{projectId}/geojson")
    @Transactional
    @ResponseBody
    public void updateGeoJson(
            @PathVariable long projectId,
            @RequestBody ProjectDTO projectDTO) throws IOException {
        Project project = projectRepository.findById(projectId)
                .orElseThrow(()-> new ProjectNotFoundException(projectId));
        boolean needUpdate = false;

        GeoJson geoJson;

        if (project.getGeoJson()!=null)
            geoJson = project.getGeoJson();
        else
            geoJson = new GeoJson();

        if(StringUtils.hasLength(projectDTO.getName())){
            projectDTO.setName(projectDTO.getName()
            );
            needUpdate = true;
        }
        GeoJsonDTO geoJsonDTO = projectDTO.getGeoJson();
        
        if(geoJsonDTO.getFeatures() != null) {
            
            geoJson.setType(geoJsonDTO.getType());

            List<Feature> featureList = new ArrayList<Feature>();

            for (FeatureDTO featureDTO : geoJsonDTO.getFeatures())
            {
                Geometry geometry = new Geometry();
                String coordinatesInString = CoordinatesConverter.arrayToString(featureDTO.getGeometry().getCoordinates());
                geometry.setCoordinates(coordinatesInString);
                geometry.setType(featureDTO.getGeometry().getType());

                Properties properties = new Properties();
                properties.setType(featureDTO.getProperties().getType());

                Feature feature = new Feature();
                feature.setType(featureDTO.getType());
                feature.setGeometry(geometry);
                feature.setProperties(properties);

                featureList.add(feature);
            }
            geoJson.setGeoJsonId(projectId);
            geoJson.setFeatures(featureList);

            needUpdate = true;
        }
        project.setGeoJson(geoJson);

        if(needUpdate)
            projectRepository.save(project);
    }
```

It doesn't update children tables. For example, if i have 3 **features** in a project table and send 2 new **features** it becomes 5 **features**. I want to delete old ones. I also tried Put Mapping. Maybe i should delete all **features** before updating, but i don't know how to delete all **features** for individual **project**. What should i do?
Hibernate logging:

[image]

Answer (score 2):

You write that you tried different "mappings" and you noted `Patch` and `Put` mapping. These are Http methods and have nothing to do with JPA.

Instead: it seems to me that the mapping from `GeoJson` to `Feature` is broken, it needs to be bi-directional.

My assumption:

- You use `spring.jpa.hibernate.ddl-auto=create-drop`

I copied your entities and ran the project; the following tables were created

- `projects`
- `geo_jsons`
- `geo_jsons_features` (superfluous & incorrect)
- `features`
- ...

This shows that your mapping is incorrect. I added bi-directional mapping for one-to-many as explained [here](https://www.baeldung.com/hibernate-one-to-many) and [here](https://vladmihalcea.com/the-best-way-to-map-a-onetomany-association-with-jpa-and-hibernate/) - and the superfluous `geo_jsons_features` table disappeared.

GeoJson:

```java
    @OneToMany(mappedBy = "geoJson", cascade = CascadeType.ALL)
    @ToString.Exclude
    private List<Feature> features = new ArrayList<>();
```

and in Feature

```java
    @ManyToOne
    @JoinColumn(name = "geo_json_id")
    private GeoJson geoJson;
```

Then I wrote a small test program and tried the cascading `save` and it worked:

```java
    @Autowired
    private ProjectRepository projectRepository;
    
    @Override
    public void run(String... args) throws Exception {
        var p = new Project();
        var g = new GeoJson();
        var f1 = new Feature();
        var f2 = new Feature();

        p.setGeoJson(g);
        g.addFeature(f1);
        g.addFeature(f2);

        projectRepository.save(p);
        // after this operation the following are true:
        // project contains 1 element
        // geoJson contains 1 element
        // feature table contains 2 elements
    }
```

Additional notes:

- If you were to use the same name for your Primary key, e.g. `id` - you could pull the declaration for `@Id` into a `@MappedSuperclass` saving you some boiler plate code
- Consider using `@CreatedDate` on `createdDateTime` and change it's type to `LocalDateTime`. Additionally add `@EntityListeners(AuditingEntityListener.class)` to that class for it to automatically set the attribute during save.
- You should add `addChild(Child c)` and `removeChild(Child c)` methods as explained [here](https://vladmihalcea.com/a-beginners-guide-to-jpa-and-hibernate-cascade-types/) (this is an excellent blog post which touches every aspect of any mapping type).